# Difference between -sn and -sL in Nmap?

Tags: nmap

Here as man page says, "-sn: Ping Scan - disable port scan", and "-sL: List Scan - simply list targets to scan"

I Tried this:

```
    ➜  ~ sudo nmap -sn scanme.nmap.org 
    Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-06-24 17:35 CST
    Cannot find nmap-payloads. UDP payloads are disabled.
    Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156)
    Host is up (0.20s latency).
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.22 seconds

    ➜  ~ sudo nmap -sL scanme.nmap.org
    Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-06-24 17:36 CST
    Nmap scan report for scanme.nmap.org (45.33.32.156)
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.02 seconds
```

Question: why using `-sn` can find one active host, but using `-sL` can't?

Answer (score 3):

When using just `-sL`, no packets are sent to the target host (`nmap` can therefore not say whether the host is up or not), it just performs a host name lookup.

From the manual:

> `-sL` (List Scan)
>
> The list scan is a degenerate form of host discovery that simply
>              lists each host of the network(s) specified, without sending any
>              packets to the target hosts. By default, Nmap still does
>              reverse-DNS resolution on the hosts to learn their names. It is
>              often surprising how much useful information simple hostnames give
>              out. For example, `fw.chi` is the name of one company's Chicago
>              firewall.
>
> Nmap also reports the total number of IP addresses at the end. The
>              list scan is a good sanity check to ensure that you have proper IP
>              addresses for your targets. If the hosts sport domain names you do
>              not recognize, it is worth investigating further to prevent
>              scanning the wrong company's network.
>
> Since the idea is to simply print a list of target hosts, options
>              for higher level functionality such as port scanning, OS detection,
>              or ping scanning cannot be combined with this. If you wish to
>              disable ping scanning while still performing such higher level
>              functionality, read up on the `-Pn` (skip ping) option.